# How to get large text between tags

Tags: php, regex, curl

I'm using cURL to get part of content from website. I don't have problem with text which is in one line, but if there is more lines which contain tags, whitespaces. Function preg_match returns null.
Here is my code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $pattern = '#<div class="class-name">([^\n]+.*?)</div>#';
    preg_match($pattern, $output, $matches);

    var_dump($matches);
```

I checked this pattern on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it should work, but as I said before preg_match returns null.
Any idea what may be a reason? I would like to get everything(include whitespaces, other tags) which is between this tag

Comment: don't parse html with regular expressions

Comment: You need the `s` modifier of the regexp to make `.*` cross multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `.*?` causes backtracking, which is limited by [`pcre.backtrack_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit)

It would be more sensible to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) or any other HTML parser to find the desired piece of data.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//div[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " class-name ")]');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue;
}
```